# Groovy and grails tool suite marketplace Maven Integration install error

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, m2eclipse

Use the marketplace in Groovy Grails Tool Suite to install Maven Integration for eclipse. But when confirming selected features, no matter I choose "Maven Integration for eclipse" ,the error remains :Cannot complete the provisioning operation. Please change your selection and try again. See below for details.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Maven Development Tools 0.2.0.201401071755 (com.ifedorenko.m2e.mavendev.feature.feature.group 0.2.0.201401071755)
  Missing requirement: Maven Development Tools 0.2.0.201401071755 (com.ifedorenko.m2e.mavendev 0.2.0.201401071755) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.launching [1.5.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Development Tools 0.2.0.201401071755 (com.ifedorenko.m2e.mavendev.feature.feature.group 0.2.0.201401071755)
    To: com.ifedorenko.m2e.mavendev [0.2.0.201401071755]
```

someone have any idea how can i resolve the problem?

Comment: Could you provide the exactly name of the plugin ?

Comment: ijust go to help-->eclipse Marketplace-->m2e-->Maven Developement Tools-->install

Answer (score 0):

By default, GGTS 3.4 already has the **m2e** plugin.
I guess, you didn't select all dependecies for the plugin, so, it can not be installed.
Or, the **Firewall** might block installing new plugins in the Eclipse. I faced this issue some times before.

Comment: so i must reinstall it?

Comment: In case, your network is under the Firewall, you might contact with the network administrator for the helps. 
Or, you can try to use GGTS 3.4