# Maven for eclipse plugin not getting installed

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

When I'm trying to download the plugin from eclipse marketplace, I get the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Maven Development Tools 0.2.0.201401071755 (com.ifedorenko.m2e.mavendev.feature.feature.group 0.2.0.201401071755)
  Missing requirement: Maven Development Tools 0.2.0.201401071755 (com.ifedorenko.m2e.mavendev 0.2.0.201401071755) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.launching [1.5.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Development Tools 0.2.0.201401071755 (com.ifedorenko.m2e.mavendev.feature.feature.group 0.2.0.201401071755)
    To: com.ifedorenko.m2e.mavendev [0.2.0.201401071755]
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496018/groovy-and-grails-tool-suite-marketplace-maven-integration-install-error

Comment: @Calon : The answer given is not clear. can you please explain the process.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I only stated that there is a similar question, not that it was answered there. What OS are you using?

Comment: @Calon : Linux Mint 16 and Eclipse kepler

Comment: It seems that you are not alone there. There are some error messages in the marketplace from users who had the same issue. E.g.: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/error/report/1744743 . Maybe you can try getting another compatible version from here: https://github.com/ifedorenko/com.ifedorenko.m2e.mavendev.

Comment: @Calon : yes i think its some issue many users are facing...now i am trying to add all the dependencies manually. Anyways, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: @gonephising It would be great if you'd add your answer here, if you have found one. It looks like the problem appears quite often. But there is no easy to find solution for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install maven plugin for eclipse luna](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500127/unable-to-install-maven-plugin-for-eclipse-luna)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem on my environment.

In the error message, you can see that the plugin you want to install need the bundle org.eclipse.m2e.launching in following versions (1.6.0 to 2.0.0).

Actually, only version 1.5 of m2e is released. You can install the milestone of version 1.6 by following these instructions.

- Help > Install new software...
- Paste the following link into the
  field Work with :
  http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.6/
- Press enter Select all plugins you need - Click Next and follow the wizard
- After this installation, retry the installation of "Maven Development
  Tools"