# Unable to install maven plugin for eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, maven-3

Iam trying to install maven plugin for eclipse luna through eclipse market place but i get the following error.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Maven Development Tools 0.3.0.201410040035 (com.ifedorenko.m2e.mavendev.feature.feature.group 0.3.0.201410040035)
  Missing requirement: Maven Development Tools 0.3.0.201409160039 (com.ifedorenko.m2e.mavendev 0.3.0.201409160039) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.launching [1.6.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Development Tools 0.3.0.201410040035 (com.ifedorenko.m2e.mavendev.feature.feature.group 0.3.0.201410040035)
    To: com.ifedorenko.m2e.mavendev [0.3.0.201409160039]
```

Please help how can i solve this problem.
All my environment variable are also set correctly.

Answer (score 6):

In fact, I have the same problem on my environment.

In the error message, you can see that the plugin you want to install need the bundle org.eclipse.m2e.launching in following versions (1.6.0 to 2.0.0).

Actually, only version 1.5 of m2e is released. You can install the milestone of version 1.6 by following these instructions.

1. Help > Install new software...
2. Paste the following link into the field Work with : http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.6/
3. Press enter
4. Select all plugins you need
5. Click Next and follow the wizard
6. After this installation, retry the installation of "Maven Development Tools"

I hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing through this update site instead:

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest Eclipse EE version it internally consist Maven plugin

Answer (score 1):

The 'Maven Development Tools' you appear to be trying to install requires that the basic 'Maven Integration for Eclipse' (m2e) is already installed.

Some downloads of Eclipse include m2e but others don't.

Install m2e using 'Help > Install New Software...'. Choose the main Luna site to work with. m2e is in the 'Collaboration' section.